# Static members = error CS0119: 'EntityCommandExecutionException' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

The code below gave the above error at point where it try to enter the `foreach`. I have checked the database table and also did a select using the parameters that was passed when I stepped through the code and it returned something.

```
var propertyItems = from x in _context.Db.tbl_BranchProperty
                    where x.BranchId == BranchId && x.ClientId == clientId
                    select x;

foreach (var propertyItem in propertyItems)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have wrapped your context object and made it static, try to create new object and initialize it properly then user your query like that.

```
yourContext db = new yourContext();
var propertyItems = db.tbl_BranchProperty
    .Where(x => x.BranchId == BranchId && x.ClientId == clientId)
    .Select(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the error was as a result of the difference between the properties of the entity `tbl_BranchProperty` and `tbl_BranchProperty` table columns.